# PHP mysql - Empty php variable used in mysql selects all rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have this variable `$search='';` which stores words typed in a search bar and an empty default value. I then execute a query like this:

```
$result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'");
```

But this query returns all rows when the $search variable is empty. And I want it to show "0" row results when it is empty.

This may have no sense at all but, I can't use a method like this:

```
if(!empty($search)){
       $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'");
}
```

I need a method that executes the same query whatever the value of `$search` is. Is there any other method?

Comment: I dont understand why you can't use `if(!empty($search))`

Comment: You're widely open to sql injection. And If you are getting empty values in `$search` then why are you querying?

Comment: `This may have no sense at all but, I can't use a method like this` could you explain this requirement? You aren't going to be able to execute that query without getting everything since you'd be using `LIKE %%` as your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your query, it'll return 0 rows if `$search` is empty.

```
$result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND '".$search."' != ''");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using IF in a WHERE query helps you:

```
$result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE IF ( '%".$search."%' = '%%', '', '%".$search."%')");
```

in case the search string is empty this will return only the empty names from the table; assuming there are no empty names in the table this will return zero results.

Answer (score -2):

Send an empty array if the search variable is empty.

```
if(!empty($search)){
       $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'");
}
else {
      $result = [];
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the result of `$conn->query()` would also be an array. The most likely culprit, `PDO::query`, returns a `PDOStatement` which would make the code behave differently depending on the contents of `$search`.